# How to solve a a full wave rectifier with two diodes and a ground in the middle?

Tags: diodes, voltage-divider, rectifier, bridge-rectifier, reverse-breakdown

This is the problem[image: QUESETION]

[image: Solution]

I am trying to follow along with the solution but I don't understand what is happening, how do I handle the random ground in the middle?? is the node between d1 and d2 40Vpeek and is the node between r1 and r2 -40V peek. I need some more explanation because I don't know what I'm not seeing?? Any kind of help is greatly appreciated, Thankyou!

Answer (score 1):

Two things I recommend when you have confusion with these puzzle pieces.

1: Break down the circuit into two, one showing current flow during the positive phase, the other during the negative phase.

This allows you to ignore "what the other diode is doing"- you don't care because it's an ideal diode in this exercise, so when reverse biased that means that current through it is __.

2: The other aspect of these puzzle problems is the way the schematic is drawn- nominally in a bridge configuration, but sometime that makes it difficult to see how the components are interconnected.  Redrawing it in a rectilinear fashion sometimes helps.

Note that ground is a relative term.  Sometimes it's convenient to call some  node "ground", but that doesn't make its voltage automatically equal to some voltage source, which is ultimately the reference source in this circuit.

Answer (score 0):

If you hooked it up to North American mains that way. That is supplied as poles (um, phases)  L1 and L2, with a center tap neutral that is earthed.  It would instantly explode with a dead short between L1 and Equipment Safety Ground  through D1, the neutral-ground equipotential bond, and neutral.   Since that did not happen,  we know the AC supply is isolated from "ground ".

So ground **should be entirely disregarded**: it is a red herring here, and the two "grounded" points can simply be considered as a wire between those points.

Don't think of there being any relationship at all between AC supply and "ground" because there isn't one.

Comment: Your answer is good except that I immediately thought, where is inductor L1. Then realized you meant line 1 (hot). You might put that in answer.

Comment: @marla good point.  Edited.

Comment: No idea why you bring up mains voltage, most of your answer just adds to the confusion. "Since this did not happen", yeah well, no one tried to connect this.